# How to change the remote view button text and notification small icon in a custom notification in Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a notification with a button, such that when clicked I get the `FULL_WAKE_LOCK`, and if I press the button again the `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` is released, because I want the screen not to turn off when I'm reading something on Chrome.

I have created a custom notification with only a single button (in different layout)... in the main activity I'm using a switch to activate and deactivate the notification...

I tried using the `.setText()` in broadcast receiver class and main class .... but doesn't seem to work...

SO HERE--> I am trying to use two layouts noti_switch --> with button text ON and noti_switch2 --> with button text OFF and swap them according to user clicks...

```
//*******THE MAIN ACTIVITY--> contains a switch to spawn Notification with custom button.....******//////
public class Main extends Activity {
    public static PowerManager pm;
    public static PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
    public static NotificationManager nm;
    public static Notification noti;
    public static Intent intent, intent2, switchIntent1;
    public static PendingIntent pending, pending2, switchPending1;
    public static RemoteViews rv;
    static Context context = null;
    public static int count = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = Main.this;

        Switch s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);

        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        intent = new Intent(context, Noti_switch.class);
        intent2 = new Intent(context, Noti_switch2.class);
        pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        pending2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
        switchIntent1 = new Intent("com.suben.onoffonnotifi.ACTION_ON");
        switchPending1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Main.this, 0, switchIntent1, 0);
        //switchPending1 = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, switchIntent1, 0);
        s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (isChecked) {
                    notiTextON();

                    //I'F I TRY TO GET SPAWN A NEW NOTIFICATION HERE WITH DIFFERENT text ...DOESN'T WORK... IT SEAMS MY PROGRAM IS STUCK IN CLASS extending BROADCAST RECEIVER
                } else if (!isChecked) {
                    if (wl != null)
                        if (wl.isHeld()) {
                            wl.release();
                        }
                    nm.cancel(0);

                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void notiTextON() {
        Context context = Main.this;
        rv = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.noti_switch);

        noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(null)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sdcard)
        //.setContentTitle("App")
        //.setContentText("ON/OFF")
        .setContentIntent(pending)
        .setContent((RemoteViews) rv).build();

        //
        noti.contentView = rv;
        noti.contentIntent = pending;
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        //
        rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, switchPending1);

        nm.notify(0, noti);
    }
    public void notiTextOFF() {
        context = Main.this;

        rv = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.noti_switch2);

        noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(null)
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_sdcard)
        //.setContentTitle("App")
        //.setContentText("ON/OFF")
        .setContentIntent(pending2)
        .setContent((RemoteViews) rv).build();

        //
        noti.contentView = rv;
        noti.contentIntent = pending2;
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        //
        rv.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, switchPending1);

        nm.notify(0, noti);

    }
}


/////***********NOW WORK.JAVA IS THE BROADCASTRECEIVER CLASS*******////

public class Work extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static Main obj;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (Main.pm == null) {
            Main.pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            Main.wl = Main.pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "Arsenal");

        }
        /*
        if(inflater==null){
        inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.noti_switch, null);
        b=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        }
        */

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("com.suben.onoffonnotifi.ACTION_ON")) {
            if (!Main.wl.isHeld()) {
                Main.wl.acquire();
                obj.notiTextOFF();        //I'M TRYING TO CREATE A NEW NOTIFICATION BUT CANT
            } else {
                if (Main.wl.isHeld()) {
                    Main.wl.release();
                    obj.notiTextON();      //I'M TRYING TO SPAWN NEW NOTIFICATION BUT CANT...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just repost your notification with the new text. Notifications with the same id will replace each other,

Comment: Thnxxxxx for the reply but.... As I'm stuck I'm broadcast receiver class I can't do it .... Can't do it in the broadçast receiver class with the Main classes' data.... Should I try creating new data in broadcast receiver class....

Comment: Yes, you can send all the data you need in the bundle